# DalekJS: Internet Explorer does not launch and the test hangs

Tags: javascript, dalekjs

I've been able to get DalekJS to run with Chrome. However, I am unable to have it run IE (either IE 9, or IE 10).

Running in Windows:
With "browser": ["chrome"] in my dalekfile:

```
C:\web-app-testing-versioned> dalek .\test\dalek-test.js
Running tests
Running Browser: Google Chrome
[9252:10268:1002/151043:ERROR:platform_thread_win.cc(127)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
OS: Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64
Browser Version: 29.0.1547.76

RUNNING TEST - "Local dev page loads"
> OPEN http://127.0.0.1:5207
* TITLE It has the expected title
* 1 Assertions run
* TEST - "Local dev page loads" SUCCEEDED

 1/1 assertions passed. Elapsed Time: 1.43 sec
->
Report type "html" written to "results"
```

With "browser": ["IE"]:

```
C:\web-app-testing-versioned> dalek .\test\dalek-test.js
Running tests
Running Browser: Internet Explorer //this is where the test hangs...
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

I didn't see a logfile, so I'm not sure what to do. Appreciate the help -- this looks like a good tool, thus far. Thanks!

Comment: Hey.

Could you please provide a gist or so of the test you are trying to run. Also, information on your node version, OS version, your dalek version & the version of your dalek-browser-ie plugin?

It works for me in my VM (Windows 7, IE 9, Node v0.10.20, dalek-browser-ie 0.0.2, dalek 0.0.6).

Thank you.

Comment: OS Version: Win 7, 64-bit; Node 0.10.20; dalek-browser-ie 0.0.2; IE 10; dalek 0.0.6; I do not know how to provide gists...

Comment: Could you please update to the latest versions of the plugins & see if the problem still exists?

Also, did you changed something in your IE settings (security, etc.).
I noticed that when you change certain parts of the IE settings, the webdriver isn't able to take control of your Browser. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @SebastianGolasch, this is an awesome tool. Just messing about with it now. I'm having similar problems in IE. It hangs on .wait or .screenshot

Comment: Hello, @SebastianGolasch!  
Sorry to have been away for so long: IE now runs. In order to remotely drive IE, the setting "Enable Protected Mode" (in IE's Security tab) must be set to the same value for ALL zones. If it is on for some zones and off for others, remote driving will not work.